# Why is my unit test failing via Hudson/Phing, but succeeding via Phing on the command line?

Tags: php, zend-framework, hudson, phpunit, phing

**General Info:**

PHP 5.3.3
PHPUnit 3.4
Zend Framework 1.10.8

**Phing build target**

```
 <target name="test">
  <echo msg="PHPUnit..." />
  <phpunit codecoverage="false" haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true" printsummary="true" bootstrap="${testdir}/application/bootstrap.php">
   <batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${testdir}">
     <include name="**/*Test.php" />
     <exclude name="./application/ControllerTestCase.php" />
     <exclude name="./application/bootstrap.php" />
    </fileset>
   </batchtest>
   <formatter type="xml" todir="${builddir}" outfile="phpunit-results.xml" />
  </phpunit>
  <phpunitreport infile="${builddir}/phpunit-results.xml" 
     styledir="${phpunit.styles.dir}"
     format="frames" 
     todir="${builddir}" />
 </target>
```

**This works...**

```
phing -f build.xml test
```

**Hudson/Phing**

My Phing target listed in Hudson, which uses the same build.xml file, does not work.  I get the same type of error (strpos(): Empty delimiter) for every unit test, which occurs whenever $this->dispatch(..url..) is executed.

**Occurs within the console output upon execution of the unit test target in Hudson**

```
'strpos(): Empty delimiter' in /opt/phing/classes/phing/tasks/ext/phpunit/PHPUnitTask.php:279
```

**Within the PHPUnit results XML file**

```
strpos(): Empty delimiter

/opt/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php:504
/opt/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php:551
/opt/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php:615
/opt/zend/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:187
/var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/trunk/tests/application/IndexControllerTest.php:6
/opt/phing/bin/phing.php:37
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: same directory where you use hudson? possible that "testdir" is the directory where hudson is located or something like this (bootstrap not found..)

Comment: Do you run your command line test with the same user credentials than Hudson? If yes, check if there is some setup for the user account done in the .profile file. This file is not executed when Hudson starts a shell. Two options. 1. call the .profile before you call phing. 2. Move the initialisation into your environment initialisation file (e.g. .env or .kshrc; find the name out from your administrator) - explanation: Hudson does not start a login shell for running the build steps, therefor the login script (.profile) will not be executed.

Comment: Hi Peter,  Thanks for your response.  I can't find the environment init. files you referenced, but I was able to add /etc/profile execution to the script.  I'm still getting the same error.  I'm unable to replicate this issue within the command line while under the Hudson user, or any other user.  I'm using CentOS 5.5 with WHM/cPanel.  Anything else you can add?  Thanks again!

Comment: Facing the same issue while running phpunit form phing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, I solved this problem, but by deciding not to run PHPUnit via a Hudson Phing target.  Instead, I decided to run a shell command in Hudson, which at the moment works fine for our needs.  If anyone has any other ideas, I'm all ears.  Thanks!